# Lucene.Net cannot parse query using RavenDB 'IN' operator on a list of empty strings

Tags: c#, lucene.net, ravendb, iqueryable

I've migrated to RavenDB 2.0 and am writing a query using the `IN` operator which is producing an error when parsing the query.

I am using an `EmbeddableDocumentStore` to isolate the issue in unit tests. I am currently running RavenDB Embedded 2.0.2230. I have tried running the same tests against RavenDB.Embedded 1.2.2033-Unstable and no error is reported.

The object being queried is straight forward:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

My setup and query is as follows:

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true };
documentStore.Initialize();

using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var list = new[] { "", "", "" };

    var query = from c in session.Query<Company>()
                where c.Country.In(list)
                select c;

    var companies = query.ToList();
}
```

The query compiles but I receive the following error when the query is parsed at runtime:

```
Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseException :
Could not parse modified query:
'@in<Country>:("EMPTY_STRING","EMPTY_STRING",[[EMPTY_STRING]]) '
original was:
'@in<Country>:([[EMPTY_STRING]],[[EMPTY_STRING]],[[EMPTY_STRING]]) '
```

As you can see the last item in the collection has been parsed differently to the preceding items. This is what seems to be causing the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you constructing your dynamic query? What are those values?

Comment: The query is just the linq statement already shown...? What values do you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, missreaded your question, something like this works?: `where c.Country.Any( c=> list.Contains( c ) )`

Comment: If instead you mean `where list.Contains(c.Country)` then, no. It compiles but will not parse as a Lucene query: "Method not supported: Contains"

Comment: I tested (on a very basic setup): `where list.Any( l => l == c.Country )` and that seems to do the right thing.

Comment: I get a similar error to the Contains approach when trying that way: Expression type not supported: System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression. I have tried it in both the unstable version from July and the latest stable version.

Comment: Why do you care about empty strings?  What are you after?

Comment: Edge case I guess. At the very least its undesirable behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in RavenDB.  There are two bugs actually, one relating to the translation exception you are getting when more than one empty string is in the list, and another that even with a single empty string, `.In()` doesn't retrieve the item with the empty string.

Raven indexes empty strings as `[[EMPTY_STRING]]` instead of `""` because Lucene would not pick up on it.  It works with `.Where(x == "")`, but it doesn't appear to work with `.Where(x.In(new[]{""}))`

I will submit an issue to their bug tracker.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This has been fixed as of RavenDB 2.0.2236-Unstable